# How to use glide library for slider image in android

Tags: android, android-glide

How to create image slider of multiple images using glide library in android ?

I have used glide for one image but not able to use for creating image slider .can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check this topic, it helps me: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10869/c%c3%b3mo-crear-slide-de-im%c3%a1genes-con-viewpager-y-glide-en-android?newreg=6914a57c15384b95b02e445f995490b1**

Following this topic I create my own Custompageradapter like that:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageViewPage";
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    String[] mResources;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] resources) {
        mContext = context;
        mResources = resources;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "instantiateItem() called with: " + "container = [" + container + "], position = [" + position + "]");

        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager, container, false);

        Log.d(TAG, "load in gallery:" + mResources[position] + "#end");
        final ImageView ivPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

        if (!mResources[position].equals("")){
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mResources[position].trim())
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(ivPhoto);
        }

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Log.d(TAG, "destroyItem() called with: " + "container = [" + container + "], position = [" + position
                + "], object = [" + object + "]");
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

And to call it, I do it like this:

```
   String[] photoUrls = {"http://example/photo.jpg",
            "http://example2.jpeg"};


    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) binding.slider;

    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getContext(), photoUrls));
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: what is the xml for this example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use android viewflipper .It is simple to use and as you have told you were able to use it for one image i hope you will figure out for multiple images and rest of your work can be completed using viewflippper.

Comment: let me try viewflipper hope it will work which i am expecting